# Construction of $x \in G$ that has no fixed point where $X$ acts on $S$ with $| S | >1$ and only one orbit.

Tags: abstract-algebra

(Lang, p. 76)
Let $G$ be a finite group operating on a finite set $S$ with $|S| >1$. Assume there is only one orbit. Prove that there exists an element $x \in G$ such that for all $s \in S$ $xs \neq s$.

How do I do this? I've tried by assuming the negation of the conclusion, but not really applicable on calculating the cardinality of any $G_s$ (the isotropy of $s$) or any info. of it. And I also tried to construct $x$ by consdiering the equalness of index of $G_s$ and the cardinality of the orbit that contains $s$, but failed.

Especially, I tried to employ the following equation in the course of solving:
$$
|S| = |Gs| = (G:G_s)
$$
for all s.

Comment: The task is essentially to prove that the union of all subgroups in a given conjugacy class (which does not consist of the group itself) can never be the whole group. This can be done via a rather simple counting argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me a direct application of the Burnside's counting lemma
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma

The order of $S/G$, which is $1$ by hypothesis, equalas the sum $\sum_{g\in G}|Fix(g)|$, divided by $G$. Since there is some element with fixed points (e.g. the identity), there must be at least one element $g$ with $Fix(g)=\emptyset$